# django No such file or directory: "common-passwords.txt.gz"

Tags: django

I get the following error when I run:  Python manage.py createsuperuser

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py", line 174, in __init__

    with gzip.open(password_list_path, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/gzip.py", line 53, in open

    binary_file = GzipFile(filename, gz_mode, compresslevel)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/gzip.py", line 163, in __init__

    fileobj = self.myfileobj = builtins.open(filename, mode or 'rb')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/project/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/common-passwords.txt.gz'
```

Comment: Looks like the file `common-passwords.txt.gz` file was deleted. Try re-installing django in your virtual environment.

Comment: Thanks Pedram Parsian!  It solved the problem.  I reinstalled Django and it works.

Comment: Glad to help :) If you don't mind, I will edit the question title and add the error message to it, so that other people can find that while searching; I also added an answer as SO suggests **not to** answer questions in the comments section.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about the `common-passwords.txt.gz` file inside django's directory. The easiest way to get the file back is to **reinstall** the django inside the virtual environment.