# I can't create super user

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, superuser, replit

I am building my website with Django. I need to create a super user but there is a huge error after I enter the user, mail, password. Without a super user, I will not be able to continue developing the project, therefore, I ask for help.
Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/laba/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py", line 210, in __init__
    with gzip.open(password_list_path, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/gzip.py", line 58, in open
    binary_file = GzipFile(filename, gz_mode, compresslevel)
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/gzip.py", line 173, in __init__
    fileobj = self.myfileobj = builtins.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/runner/.cache/pip/pool/d4/1e/2a/common-passwords.txt.gz'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/runner/laba/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/runner/laba/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/runner/laba/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/runner/laba/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/runner/laba/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/runner/laba/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 157, in handle
    validate_password(password2, self.UserModel(**fake_user_data))
  File "/home/runner/laba/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py", line 44, in validate_password
    password_validators = get_default_password_validators()
  File "/home/runner/laba/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py", line 19, in get_default_password_validators
    return get_password_validators(settings.AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS)
  File "/home/runner/laba/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py", line 30, in get_password_validators
    validators.append(klass(**validator.get('OPTIONS', {})))
  File "/home/runner/laba/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py", line 213, in __init__
    with open(password_list_path) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/runner/.cache/pip/pool/d4/1e/2a/common-passwords.txt.gz'
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django No such file or directory: "common-passwords.txt.gz"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59534987/django-no-such-file-or-directory-common-passwords-txt-gz)

Comment: Can you show your `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` setting? Do you set `password_list_path` by any chance?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat no

Answer (score 1):

Before create superuser:

```
Python manage.py migrate.
```

After then:

```
Python manage.py createsuperuser
```

good luck.

Comment: did not help...